# Empty response from Google Cloud Vision DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, ocr, google-cloud-vision

I have a Python function that calls Google's Cloud Vision API to OCR a pdf file. It works most of the time, but sometimes it returns an empty response. Sometimes it also returns the correct data for the first page and then empty data for the others.

The code I'm using is the following:

```
from google.cloud import vision

def ocr(filename):

    mime_type = 'application/pdf'
    batch_size = 100

    feature = vision.types.Feature(type=vision.enums.Feature.Type.DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION)
    gcs_source = vision.types.GcsSource(uri=filename)
    input_config = vision.types.InputConfig(gcs_source=gcs_source, mime_type=mime_type)
    image_context = vision.types.ImageContext(language_hints=['pt'])

    request = vision.types.AnnotateFileRequest(
        features=[feature],
        input_config=input_config,
        image_context=image_context
    )

    operation = vision_client.batch_annotate_files(requests=[request])
    return operation.responses[0]
```

The latest PDF to give me this problem is a 4-page pdf, stored in GCS. It is a clean scanned document with text on all 4 pages. The result it gives me is the following:

```
responses {
  full_text_annotation {}
  context {page_number: 1}
}
responses {
  full_text_annotation {}
  context {page_number: 2}
}
responses {
  full_text_annotation {}
  context {page_number: 3}
}
responses {
  full_text_annotation {}
  context {page_number: 4}
}
total_pages: 4
```

I'm on Python 3.6 and Google Cloud Vision v. 0.40.0

Comment: Tried to replicate your scenario in Python 3.7.3 but it's working good for me. Does this happens with this particular document or with all the documents?